# Simplification of a complicated fraction

Tags: physics, fractions

I am going over a physics text and I have difficulty to see how one can go from 
$$2A = (1+ \frac{\alpha}{ik})(1+\frac{ik}{\alpha})\frac{Fe^{ika}e^{-\alpha a}}{2} +  (1- \frac{\alpha}{ik})(1-\frac{ik}{\alpha})\frac{Fe^{ika}e^{\alpha a}}{2}$$
to
$$\frac{Ae^{-ika}}{F} = \cosh(\alpha a) + i(\frac{\alpha^2 - k^2}{2k \alpha})\sinh(\alpha a)$$ 
Could you give me some hints on how to proceed? I, obviously, know $\cosh(x) = \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$ and $\sinh(x) = \frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$ but the connection between the two steps is not obvious to me.

Comment: Have you made any progress in getting to the desired equation? If so, would you be able to show us your working so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dividing by $2e^{ik\alpha}F$ gives
$$\frac{Ae^{-ik\alpha}}F=\left(1+\frac\alpha{ik}\right)
\left(1+\frac{ik}\alpha\right)\frac{e^{-a\alpha}}4
+\left(1-\frac\alpha{ik}\right)
\left(1-\frac{ik}\alpha\right)\frac{e^{a\alpha}}4.$$
Next,
$$\left(1+\frac\alpha{ik}\right)
\left(1+\frac{ik}\alpha\right)=\frac{(ik+\alpha)^2}{ik\alpha}
=\frac{2k\alpha+i(k^2-\alpha^2)}{k\alpha}$$
and similarly
$$\left(1-\frac\alpha{ik}\right)
\left(1-\frac{ik}\alpha\right)=\frac{2k\alpha-i(k^2-\alpha^2)}{k\alpha}.$$
Then,
$$\frac{Ae^{-ik\alpha}}F=\frac{e^{-a\alpha}+e^{a\alpha}}2
+i\frac{k^2-\alpha^2}{2k\alpha}\frac{e^{-a\alpha}-e^{a\alpha}}2
$$
which equals
$$\cosh a\alpha+i\frac{\alpha^2-k^2}{2k\alpha}\sinh a\alpha.$$

Comment: I think you forgot a factor of 2 in the denominator of the very last fraction. Other than that, it is perfect. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Multiply your first equation by $$\frac{e^{-ika}}{2F}$$
and expanding your paranthesis we get
$$\left(2+\frac{\alpha}{ik}+\frac{ik}{\alpha}\right)e^{-\alpha a}+\left(2-\frac{ \alpha}{ik}-\frac{ik}{\alpha}\right)e^{\alpha a}$$